# A box alignment algebra

Tags: algorithm, text, alignment, algebra

I'm looking for an algorithm (or algebra) for 2d box alignment. The alignment of (recursive) boxes is implemented in type setting systems like TeX and Lout but also in web browsers. For example, boxes can be aligned horizontally or vertically, spread over available space and recursively composed.  Are there papers or implementations out there that implement such systems outside of type setting? Is there a consensus how such systems are best described?

Edit: The [Haskell Diagrams](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/) package looks like a pretty thorough approach for composing graphical objects. It can deal with any shape, not just boxes. It's weak spot seems to be dealing with text which is very important for type setting, web browsers, and GUIs.

Edit: [Coffins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44159/3083) in LaTeX3 look relevant.

Comment: As a further area to investigate: GUI frameworks also use these algorithms to place widgets in windows. Often, windows can be resized and the layout has to adapt accordingly. As far as I can tell, similar ideas are used everywhere but no system is exactly like the other.